Question about Durvasa's Mantras and Kunti
I'm no Sanskrit scholar and I've only read abridged versions of the Mahabharata in Hindi and watched a few TV adaptations, but parts of the story got me thinking.
If Rishi Durvasa's mantra could invoke any deity to get son, why did Pandu, Kunti or Madri never consider invoking Shiva, Vishnu or Durga for their children?
I'd appreciate some thoughts and analysis from both a literary and religious perspective.

Kuntī followed the wishes of Pāṇḍu, it was Pāṇḍu who told her to invoke Dharma, Vāyu, and Indra.
Why did Pāṇḍu think of invoking these devatās? Well, he states his wants pretty clearly when he tells his wishes to Kuntī, that he wants a strong, etc. son, and so on. Why didn't Pāṇḍu think of invoking Viṣṇu or Śiva? Well, you might even ask, why didn't Pāṇdu think of invoking Varuṇa, Sūrya, Agni, Brahmā, etc.? That is honestly a pointless question

The mantra is for Kuntī to invoke devas for the sake of having an offspring through them. Durgā is a devatā, but she isn't a deva. Note devatā is strīliṅga, but it may be used for both deva and devī. And deva is pulliṅga.

@Bingming it is pointless perhaps from a religious perspective, but it is an interesting question to ask from a literary perspective of the mythos. Not that there would be a definite answer but there could be scholarly theories for the same.

Elsewhere I read Kunti wanted to test the efficacy of the Mantra more out of a childish curiosity.

@Narasimham that was how she got Karna and that does not answer my question.

After testing as above to put the mantra to use her instinct/natural options were celestial Gods of Nature. This gives her power beyond the Earth. In order of serial preference the Kshatriya queen Kunti chose the 1) Sun god, 2) the god of Death (who can postpone death of her son )  3) god of Wind Power (who can move anything)  4) god of Heavenly gods of  Swarga Loka and 5),6) the Ashwini gods for sons' health and mobility.

@Narasimham Those were not her instincts according to the lore itself. She invokes the Gods she does as a result of what her husband Pandu requests. This is the same for Madri's children. My question is more about the meta of the lore itself. It's not why they chose the Gods they chose but rather why they did not choose Gods like Shiva or Vishnu. Makes sense for why they would not choose Brahma as he is not worshipped according to the overall mythos driving the lore.
